# this simple shortcode doesn't generate Collapse as supposed

Tags: shortcode

I've added a simple shortcode into my `functions.php` file which results in creating an Bootstrap Collapse into post. But when I try using that shortcode the accordion structure is not as supposed. Here's my code in `functions.php` file:

```
function sth_collapse($atts, $content = null) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
      'title'       => 'Click Me',
       ),
    $atts,
    'collapse'
    );  
    $coll  = '<div class="collapse-container">';
       $coll .= '<a href="#collapse-content" data-toggle="collapse" class="collapse-header">' . $atts['title'] . '</a>';
       $coll .= '<div id="collapse-content" class="collapse">' . $content . '</div>';
    $coll .= '</div>';
    return $coll;
}
add_shortcode('collapse', 'sth_collapse');
```

When I put that in test using `[collapse title="show"]test test[/collapse]` s shortcode generates this weird HTML structure:

```
<div class="collapse-container">
   <a class="collapse-header collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-content" aria-expanded="false">Show</a>
   <div id="collapse-content" class="collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;"></div>
</div>
<br>
test test
<br>
<div class="collapse-container">
  <a class="collapse-header collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-content" aria-expanded="false">Click Me</a>
  <div id="collapse-content" class="collapse"></div>
</div>
```

Did you notice how everything is duplicated ? 2 `.collapse-container`, 2 `collapse-header`, etc. Also for first `.collapse-header` title att defined in shortcode appears and for the second one the default title att. Also `$content` appears in wrong position, it shows all the time and clicking `a` doesn't trigger collapsing behavior. So I can say almost nothing worked fine, as I expect.
I looked at my `add_shortcode` callback function codes several times but I couldn't figure out what's wrong with that. Could you please help me on this ?

Comment: `[collapse title="show"]test test[/collapse]` works fine for me. From the output, it looks like, closing collapse missing "/" causing it to echo the collapse html again.

Comment: What a mistake, you're right @M-R :| , that was because my native language is rtl, and switching between rtl & ltr caused a simple but important mistake `[collapse/]` which I've stuck at for 2 or 3 hours. Thanks @M-R for give me the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure, your closing [collapse] does not miss "/" or is not converting to "[collapse/]".

Answer (score 0):

With the code in the functions.php, are you including all the required Bootstrap assets that are need ? Bootstrap collapse needs css and bootstrap.min.js to properly work.